# PST: Error in names(StCol) <- A : attempt to set an attribute on NULL

Tags: r, markov, traminer, pst

Consider the following code:

```
library(PST)
library(TraMineR)
library(RCurl)

x <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/c79be941bc86274f4526705600962789/raw/6e3ee8d464c97f1c26631d604de41ca97dc22159/sequence_data.csv")
data <- read.csv(text = x)
data.seq <- seqdef(data[,2:ncol(data)], missing = "%")
pstree(data.seq)
```

This generates the following error message:

```
Error in names(StCol) <- A : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

I cannot see any reason why this should generate an error. The data works fine with multiple `TraMineR` functions, e.g.

```
seqient(data.seq)
```

What is the reason for this error message? How can I overcome it?

Comment: `StCol` is the color palette used by `pstree`. The error occurs probably because you have no color palette assigned to your `data.seq` object, which has more than 12 states. Try to assign one with the `cpal` argument of `seqdef`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pstree` function of `PST` expects a state sequence object with a valid non-null `cpal` attribute. A default `cpal` color palette is automatically assigned by the `TraMineR` `seqdef` function only as long as the alphabet contains no more than 12 elements. In your example data, the alphabet is of size 29. Therefore, you need to explicitly define the color palette.

You can check that the code below (where I use package `viridis` to define the color palette) runs without error.

```
library(PST)
library(TraMineR)
library(RCurl)
library(viridis)
x <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/c79be941bc86274f4526705600962789/raw/6e3ee8d464c97f1c26631d604de41ca97dc22159/sequence_data.csv")
data <- read.csv(text = x)
data[data=="%"] <- NA
## n: size of alphabet 
n <- length(seqstatl(data[,2:ncol(data)]))
## defining color palette
cpal <- viridis_pal(option = "D")(n)
data.seq <- seqdef(data[,2:ncol(data)], cpal=cpal)
seqdplot(data.seq)
pst.tree <- pstree(data.seq)
```